# Jquery JSON in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

How do I get all the filenames in the php file with jQuery getjson?

**Json encoded data from PHP**

[{"Filename":"941-2"},{"Filename":"941"}]

**My code:**

```
$.getJSON('json.php',{id: id, ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
     $('#filename').append(j[0].Filename);
 })
```

Comment: I need to add som kind of looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a simple forloop on j.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
    $('#filename').append(j[i].FileName);
```

Comment: I only get the first filename.

Comment: I've tested it on my end and it works fine. Make sure json.php is returning the correct data.

Comment: json.php is returning the same data as I posted. Can see it if i manual go to the php file. Is it because the data is from multidimensional array with json_encode ?

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `console.log(j)`?

Comment: How do I make that output with jquery in PHP file?

Comment: Right after `function(j) {`, place `console.log(j)`, open the console with F12 and tell us what you see.

Comment: Opening the console will automatically clear your cache and show any errors with JavaScript -> 2 birds/1 stone.